# How to make Excel chart axis start NOT at major unit?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is it possible to have an Excel chart where the axis does NOT start at the major unit?
See the example below, where I want the x-axis to start at the year 2007, but have major unit 5 years and show 2010, 2015 and 2020.

I know you can move the vertical axis using the 'Vertical axis crosses''  setting, but in that case the x-axis is extended to the left of the vertical axis, which is not what I want.

**This is what I want:**

[image: What I want]

**This is the best I can do (but not good enough, see the yellow marks):**

[image]

Comment: I don't think the issue was ever adequately resolved, but you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9488457/657668) helpful.

Comment: Same problem here!! Another feature missing in Excel. Microsoft only adds flowers for each new version instead of useful features. Microsoft programmers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quickest (and I think easiest) way to do this is:

1. Chart your data as-is (I prefer a scatter/XY chart for this type of chart).
2. Format your horizontal axis to use 2007 as your Minimum and set Axis Labels to None.
3. Add a helper column to your data called Labels, set all of your values to =NA(), then set the values you want to label on your axis (2010, 2015, 2020, etc...) to 0.  The =NA() points won't plot, but the 0 points will plot on the minimum value, which is also the horizontal axis.
4. Add your Label data to the chart.  You should have a point for each Label.
5. Format your series for Line and Marker to None (or marker to built-in cross if you want a tick).
6. Add data labels to your Label series, and format to X Value and position Below.

Here's a sample:

[image: Odd Axis Label Spacing]

Comment: Great example of using a dummy series to replace axis labels. I am sure in a real-world example you aoulw clean up the labels from the real data series ;-). Well done for taking the effort to actually build and screenshot this to show that it works.